# Update query in SQL Express using textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["project"].ConnectionString.ToString());
     conn.Open();
     string arun = "UPDATE [RECEIVE] SET [RDDF2]=@RDFF2 WHERE [OIESN]=@SRT";
     string SR2 = TextBox1.Text;
     int SR = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
     string SR1 = TextBox9.Text;

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     cmd.CommandText = arun;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SRT", SR);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RDFF2", SR1);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
}
```

It is not showing error but not updating in database.

Comment: can you please put try / catch .. it will help u more

Comment: Check the return value of [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx): "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command"

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["project"].ConnectionString.ToString());

        string arun = "UPDATE [RECEIVE] SET [RDDF2]=@RDFF2 WHERE [OIESN]=@SRT";
        string SR2 = TextBox1.Text;
        int SR = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        string SR1 = TextBox9.Text;

        using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(arun, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SRT", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SR;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RDFF2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SR1;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```